# The implementation of Sequence interface is not sufficient to be a Sequence

Tags: python, collections, duck-typing, abc

I've noticed that duck typing works reasonably well up to a certain point in checking whether a class is an instance of an abstract class.

For example, to be an instance of `collections.abc.Sized`, we only need to define a `__len__()` method:

```python
import collections.abc

class MySized:
    def __len__(self):
        return 0

assert isinstance(MySized(), collections.abc.Sized)  # It is
```

In the same way, we can define classes that implement interfaces of `Container`, `Iterable`, `Collection`, and so on.

Failure befell me when I tried to write my own `Sequence`.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), as well as the code at [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L1006), a `Sequence` should be a `Collection`, a `Reversible`, and additionally implement methods `__getitem__()`, `index()` and `count()`.

But duck typing is not enough:

```python
import collections.abc

class MySequence:
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return None

    def __len__(self):
        return 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([])

    def __reversed__(self):
        return reversed([])

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return True

    def index(self, value, start=0, stop=None):
        return 0

    def count(self, value):
        return 0

assert isinstance(MySequence(), collections.abc.Collection)  # Ok
assert isinstance(MySequence(), collections.abc.Reversible)  # Ok
assert isinstance(MySequence(), collections.abc.Sequence)  # Fail! It's not
```

Of course, if we explicitly inherit a class from an abstract base class, it works:

```python
import collections.abc

class MySequence(collections.abc.Sequence):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return None

    def __len__(self):
        return 0

assert isinstance(MySequence(), collections.abc.Sequence)  # It is
```

It would be interesting to understand the reasons for this behaviour and the limits of applicability of the interface implementation only. Perhaps I missed some other undocumented method? Or for some containers it's becoming necessary to explicitly inherit from an abstract ancestor?

Comment: Did you read footnote 1 on that table in the docs? It explicitly indicates which ABCs you don't need to explicitly register implementations of.

Comment: Many thanks, @jonrsharpe, I completely overlooked that footnote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) (emphasis mine):

> An `issubclass()` or `isinstance()` test for an interface works in one
> of three ways.
>
> 1. A newly written class can inherit directly from one of the abstract
>    base classes
> 2. Existing classes and built-in classes can be registered as “virtual
>    subclasses” of the ABCs.
> 3. **Some simple interfaces** are directly recognizable by the
>    presence of the required methods (unless those methods have been set
>    to `None`). **Complex interfaces do not support this last technique**
>    because an interface is more than just the presence of method names.
>    **For example, knowing that a class supplies `__getitem__`,
>    `__len__`, and `__iter__` is insufficient for distinguishing a
>    `Sequence` from a `Mapping`.**

Without explicit inheritance you are relying on case 3, which is explicitly stated to not work for Sequences.